# Sierra - File is damaged, can't open

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

When I tried to set up some of downloaded apps in Sierra, there were always prompts which states "File is damaged, can't open.". Have googled for a while, seems the solution for this is rebooting into the safe mode, then blah, blah, but I really don't want to do that, you know, worry about there would introduce a potential safety hole out there. My question is, is there any other better way to solve this? Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the Terminal, then "sudo bash", [password here], then "xattr -cr /Applications/[app_name].app", hit your return key, done. Now go set your app up again, it should be fine now.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug with the current version of Gatekeeper.
It can be mitigated by issuing the following command in Terminal using SU credentials:
    `sudo spctl --master-disable`

Although keep in mind that disabling Gatekeeper will prevent OS X from scanning for Malware in downloaded Apps and files. So use at your own risk.

Comment: This information seems inaccurate. I don't think it's a bug, but by design, as I understand it. (Do you have a reference for why you think it's a bug?) It's telling you that the application is not properly signed, so it isn't trustable given the level of security you've selected in the Gatekeeper preferences.

Comment: I think sometimes it is a bug because sometimes I cannot open a pages file that I created myself...